# AWS CloudFront: Not showing IAM SSL certificates

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to install a DigiCert Wildcard SSL on a CloudFront CDN.

It worked immediately with all Elastic load balancers, but it's not showing up the CloudFront SSL certificate selection dropdown, even if the certificate is found in the IAM store.

Any ideas what permissions could be conflicting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If you want to use the same certificate both for CloudFront and for
>   other AWS services, you must upload the certificate twice: once for
>   CloudFront and once for the other services.

From here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/SecureConnections.html#CNAMEsAndHTTPS

Comment: CloudFront: If you are uploading a server certificate specifically for use with Amazon CloudFront distributions, you must specify a path using the --path option. The path must begin with /cloudfront and must include a trailing slash (for example, /cloudfront/test/). Enter the following command:

Answer (score 5):

This is what tripped me up:

> All certificates in ACM are regional resources, including the certificates that you import. To use the same certificate with Elastic Load Balancing load balancers in different AWS regions, you must import the certificate into each region where you want to use it. **To use a certificate with Amazon CloudFront, you must import it into the US East (N. Virginia) region**. For more information, see Supported Regions.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/import-certificate.html

Comment: Thank you so much - this was not at all intuitive and your answer helped short circuit what I'm sure would have been a few hours of hair pulling.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is not intuitive at all :/

Answer (score 1):

this is because when you upload SSL certificate for cloudfront, you need to give --path option as /cloudfront/

The command would look like this:

```
aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name YourCertificateName --certificate-body file://cert.pem --private-key file://key.pem --certificate-chain file://ca.pem --path /cloudfront/
```

If you have already uploaded certificate then you can update it with following command:

```
aws iam update-server-certificate --server-certificate-name YourCertificateName --new-path /cloudfront/
```